# VM Failover on KVM

Tags: kvm

My environment has 2 VM on Linux KVM which is installed on separate physical host, the VM’s are basically website with database running on `iis` & `mssql`. One is active & second is passive.

Is there anything which can replicate and make the secondary `VM` live on failure of primary?

Note: There is no storage devices connected to bare metal server.
the `VM` are `windows 2008`

Any suggestion is accepted.

Comment: On "failover" of primary or on "failure" of primary?